# Kubernetes AntiAffinity - limit max number of same pods per node

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster with 4 nodes. I have a pod deployed as a deployment, with 8 replicas. When I deployed this, kubernetes sometimes schedule 4 pods in node1, and the rest of the 4 pods in node2. In this case node3 and node4 don't have this container running (but other containers running there)

I do understand Pod affinity and [anti-affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity) , where they have the [Zookeeper](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/zookeeper/#tolerating-node-failure) example for pod-anti-affinity, which is great. This would make sure that no 2 pods would deploy on the same node.

This is fine, however my requirement is slightly different where I want to restrict the maximum number of the pods k8s can deploy to one node with node anti-affinity.

I need to make sure that not more than 3 instance of same pods are deployed on a node in my above example. I thought of setting a memory/cpu limit on pods but that seemed like a bad idea as I have nodes with different configuration. Is there any way to achieve this?

( Update 1 ) - I understand that my questions wasn't clear enough. To clarify further, what I want is to limit the instance of a pod to a maximum of 3 per node for a particular deployment. Example, how do I tell k8s to not deploy more than 3 instances of nginx pod per node? The restriction should only be applied to the nginx deployments and not other deployments.

( Update 2 ) - To further explain with a scenario. 
A k8s cluster, with 4 worker nodes. 
2 Deployments

1. A nginx deployment -> replicas = 10
2. A custom user agent deployment -> Replicas 10

Requirement - Hey kubernetes, I want to schedule 10 Pods of the "custom user agent" pod (Pod #2 in this example) in 4 nodes, but I want to make sure that each node may have only a maximum of 3 pods of the 'custom user agent'. For the 'nginx' pod, there shouldnt' be any such restriction, which means I don't mind if k8s schedule 5 nginx in one node and the rest of the 5 in the second node.

Comment: Any luck here?  It's the exact problem I'm having, because I have to use "hostNetwork: true", so I can only accomodate a limited, maximum number of Pods per Node.

Answer (score 4):

I myself didn't find official documentation for this. but i think you can use podantiaffinity with `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` option. this will prevent k8s from placing the same pods on a single node, but if that is not possible it will select the most eligible existing node. official doc [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/)

```
affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchLabels:
              name: deployment-name
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
        weight: 100
```

Comment: Do you know if all nodes have at least 1 pod and some have two will it preferentially schedule the new pod to the nodes with 1 before scheduling to a node with 2 pods?  It seems a logical implementation but I can't find explicit documentation about it.

Answer (score 2):

So setting a bare minimum number of pod for each node can be achieved by *topologykey*

Yes, you can achieve a pod to spawn on every node by a deployment object by pod affinity with [topologykey](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#always-co-located-in-the-same-node) set as **"kubernetes.io/hostname"**.

With the above example, you will have the following behaviour:

[image: topology key]

I hope thats what you are looking for:
[image]

Comment: Actually it's the opposite way, how to I set a maximum number of same pods per node ?

Comment: That's clearly not achievable. For scheduling you can go and change the source code of scheduler or write some algorithm for the node part. Also for something like this if you move to managed services things get pretty tied up. So you should look on the implementation part in a well architected format.

Comment: set your request: so you divide resources (memory non compressible). you would also need taints and tolerations to ensure only your pod types will match those nodes so the math works out.

Answer (score 1):

That feature is in alpha, I believe it is called `topologyKey`, depending on your Kubernetes version you may be able to use it.  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/

Comment: How do we limit the pods on a container, that's where I'm stuck

Comment: What do you mean by limit a pod on a container? A pod is an array of containers, if you want to limit the containers then just dont add them to the podSpecArray

Comment: Sorry I meant to say Limit the total number of pods running on a "node". I don't want to impose a global pod limit as @suren suggested. The limit should only applicable for one pod

Comment: In other words, how to limit the maximum instance of same pod running on a node ? For example if there is a nginx pod, how can I make sure that k8s deploys no more than 4 instances of nginx pods per node? The restriction should only be applied to that particular deployment. All other deployments should not be affected

Comment: I have updated the question with an example. I hope it makes more sense and clarifies my question further.

Comment: No that's not possible. And not a feature request too. Kubernetes already has a load balancing feature on top of the nodes of the cluster and then there's ingress controller and service mesh for traffic routing. You are expecting something without a use-case. You should have a clear cut usecase, so my question would be why?

Comment: Here is another use-case: When using volumes on Azure with "azure-disk", you can only provision 4 volumes per node (hard limit by Azure with our current VMs). So I need to tell the scheduler, please only deploy 4 of my postgres pods (with a volume for each) per node

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to achieve can be done via `maxSkew` parameter of pod topology spread constraints. Please check the original documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/